# Error: PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am having trouble with is stored procedure. I keep getting this error:
Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Error: PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

This is what i tried to run:

```
create or replace procedure service_order_proc
(
SERVICE_ORDER_ID NUMBER,
CUST_ID NUMBER,
EMP_ID NUMBER,
SERVICE_DATE DATE,
SERVICE_ORDER_STATUS_ID NUMBER,
SERVICE_ORDER_TYPE_ID NUMBER,
SERVICE_TOTAL NUMBER,

EMP_ID NUMBER,
FNAME VARCHAR2,
LNAME VARCHAR2,
PNUMBER VARCHAR2,
EMP_STATUS_ID NUMBER,
EMP_GROUP_ID NUMBER

)

AS BEGIN 

insert into service_order values (SERVICE_ORDER_ID, CUST_ID, EMP_ID, SERVICE_DATE,
SERVICE_ORDER_STATUS_ID, SERVICE_ORDER_TYPE_ID, SERVICE_TOTAL);

insert into employee values (EMP_ID, FNAME, LNAME, PNUMBER,
EMP_STATUS_ID, EMP_GROUP_ID);

end;
```

Answer (score 7):

you have `EMP_ID` listed twice as a parameter to the procedure